# Notification extension gives error while running to real device

Tags: ios, swift, onesignal

Can someone assist me with the issue i'm getting while trying to run the app in on real device.
I'm using one signal for notifications and it works fine if "Notification Extension" is not enabled.

[image]

Comment: Did you share related libraries with Notification Extension target? Each target has separate containers so you should share related files/libraries with Notification Extension target. You can add PixelBuffer related library to Targets > Notification Extension > General > Frameworks and Libraries.

Comment: Hey @Serhat , thanks for the advice i simply added "import AVFoundation" to NotificationService.swift file and it worked